# Prevent a Task Continuation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using Task continuations for a long running operation on a WinForm project.

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());

var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(result => DoSomeMoreWork(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(result => DoFinalWork(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

I only want to continue to task3 if some conditions are met on the DoSomeMoreWork() function that executes on task2. How can this be done?

Comment: WOW another greek working with TPL! Have to tweet this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

> a user-defined value can be passed from the antecedent to its
>   continuation in the Result property, so that the output of the
>   antecedent can serve as input for the continuation

So one way would be in task3, check the Result from task2 before doing any work.

```
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(result => DoSomeMoreWOrk(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(x => DoFinalWork(x.Result));
```

Where the Result returned from task2 determines what happens in task3.

***EDIT***
Another solution would be to cancel task2 if certain conditions are not met within the operation. Then the continuation task is not even scheduled.

From MSDN

> To prevent a continuation from executing if its antecedent is
>   canceled, specify the NotOnCanceled option when you create the
>   continuation.

So task3 definition becomes

```
var task3 = task2.ContinueWith(result => DoFinalWork(), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCancelled);
```

Comment: I don't think using cancellation this way is a good idea, you don't want to cancel `task2`. But giving a `CancellationToken` to `task3` that can be cancelled from `task2` would make sense.

Comment: @svik Would that prevent task3 from being scheduled?

Comment: Yes, if you cancel the token before it starts. That's what the cancellation token that you can specify when you create a `Task` is for.

Comment: Token allows you to cancel a task in a running operation or preventing it from running if IsCancellationRequested = true when passed to a task. The question was if it would prevent it from being scheduled.

Comment: Sorry about that! Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert task2 and task3 to nested tasks, executing them only if a condition is met.

Assuming DoSomeMoreWork returns true to do this, you could write something like this

```
        var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoSomeWork);
        var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(result =>
            {
                if (DoSomeMoreWork())
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(DoFinalWork, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

If you can use the Async CTP or .NET 4.5 (I think both have a Go Live license), you can replace the continuations with async/await for much cleaner code.

If you convert the worker functions to use async, your code becomes almost as clear as the synchronous version:

```
    private static async void WorkAsync()
    {
        await DoSomeWork();
        if (await DoSomeMoreWork())
        {
            await DoFinalWork();
        }
    }

    private static async Task DoFinalWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    }

    private static async Task<bool> DoSomeMoreWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some More");
        return true;
    }

    private static async Task DoSomeWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some");
    }
```

If you don't want to return Tasks from the methods, you can use the following code:

```
    private static async void WorkAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>DoSomeWork());
        if (await Task.Run(()=>DoSomeMoreWork()))
        {
            await Task.Run(()=>DoFinalWork());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was just typing a reply to your first comment about changing my code to .NET 4.5 with async/await, as it seems much cleaner! 
I just haven't downloaded the RC at work yet. Ευχαριστω!

Comment: I've been using the Async CTP for over a year now to clean up the spaghetti caused by multiple continuations. Haven't regretted it.